# What could go wrong by ignoring dot pattern in Agda?

Tags: agda

I am a noob in agda and reading http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~ulfn/papers/afp08/tutorial.pdf. My shallow knowledge somehow finds dot pattern not quite necessary. For example,

```
data Image_∋_ {A B : Set}(f : A → B) : B → Set where
  im : (x : A) → Image f ∋ f x


inv : {A B : Set}(f : A → B)(y : B) → Image f ∋ y → A
inv f .(f x) (im x) = x
```

I find `inv` can well be defined as

```
inv : {A B : Set}(f : A → B)(y : B) → Image f ∋ y → A
inv _ _ (im x) = x
```

because from the types, we've already known `y` is an image of `f` for some `x`, so it cannot possibly go wrong.

Another example is

```
data _==_ {A : Set}(x : A) : A → Set where
  refl : x == x

data _≠_ : ℕ → ℕ → Set where
  z≠s : {n : ℕ} → zero ≠ suc n
  s≠z : {n : ℕ} → suc n ≠ zero
  s≠s : {n m : ℕ} → n ≠ m → suc n ≠ suc m


data Equal? (n m : ℕ) : Set where
  eq : n == m → Equal? n m
  neq : n ≠ m → Equal? n m


equal? : (n m : ℕ) → Equal? n m
equal? zero zero    = eq refl
equal? zero (suc _) = neq z≠s
equal? (suc _) zero = neq s≠z
equal? (suc n') (suc m') with equal? n' m'
... | eq refl   = eq refl
... | neq n'≠m' = neq (s≠s n'≠m')
```

consider `equal?` function, the second last line is written in the paper as `(suc n') (suc .n') | eq refl   = eq refl`. Again, `eq refl` in with construct has provided a proof, for these two values being the same, so why do I bother writing them out using dot pattern?

I am more familiar with coq, and I am not aware of similar thing in coq. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Coq you write the pattern-matches explicitly whereas Agda's equation-based approaches forces the typechecker to reconstruct a case-tree which ought to correspond to what you wrote.

Dotted-patterns help the typechecker see that a given pattern was not the product of a match but rather *forced* by a match on one of the other arguments (e.g.: a match on a `Vec Bool n` will force the value of `n`, or a match on an equality proof will, as you've observed, force some variables to be the same).

They're not always necessary and, in fact, some have been slowly made optional as you can see in [the CHANGELOG for version 2.5.3](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Agda-2.5.3/changelog):

> Dot patterns.
>
> The dot in front of an inaccessible pattern can now be skipped if the pattern consists entirely of constructors or literals. For example:

Comment: thank you. so in my example above, is there any difference made by doing `...` instead of dot pattern? also, are there any cases where dot pattern can make substantial differences, rather than simply allowing to elide inaccessible pattern?

Comment: No difference at all. In theory having dot patterns could speed up typechecking (less information to reconstruct means a lighter workload) but I'm not sure it'd be observable.